# Open bootstrap confirmaion box on doubleclick

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, double-click, confirmation

How can i set the bootstrap confirmation box to appear only on double click event. My current code for popup is:

JS

```
$('[data-toggle="confirmation"]').confirmation({
  'onConfirm': function() {
alert("dfgdfg");
  },
  btnOkLabel: "&nbsp;Yes",
  btnCancelLabel: "&nbsp;No"
});
```

HTML

```
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>

<a href="#Delete" id="try_it" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" title="Continue?" data-toggle="confirmation" data-singleton="true" data-placement="top" data-popout="true">
<span title="Excluir o projeto">Try</span>
</a>
```

And Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/Sanal_5/q13cor4g/2/

Comment: use `dblclick` event

Comment: where? i have not set any 'click' event. popup comes up on clicking each row with attribute " data-toggle='confirmation' ". should i give the code 'bootstrap-confimation.js'?

Comment: could make a [fiiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) for your code ?

Comment: Sorry i am not able to make a fiddle, it doesn't popup on click event there. Can you make me a simple example please, which works on double click. This is where i found it from. http://mistic100.github.io/Bootstrap-Confirmation/

Comment: @Raviteja I have updated with better understandable code, and included a fiddle also.